# Пунктуация при приложении с зависимыми словами

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Как известно из Розенталя,

> Возможно дефисное присоединение приложения при наличии пояснительного
> слова (определения)... *известный экспериментатор-изобретатель*

А какова пунктуация, если к приложению прилагается (простите за тавтологию) зависимое слово? *"Известный экспериментатор-изобретатель вечного двигателя"*, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Начнем с правила:**

Розенталь, § 19. Обособленные приложения, пункт 2, примечание 2
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Возможно дефисное присоединение приложения при наличии **пояснительного слова** (определения), которое по смыслу может относиться:

1. **ко всему сочетанию**: известный экспериментатор-изобретатель; ловкий акробат-жонглёр;
2. **только к определяемому слову**: демобилизованный офицер-ракетчик; оригинальный художник-самоучка; моя соседка-педагог;
3. **только к приложению**: женщина-врач **с большим стажем**.

2. *Известный экспериментатор-изобретатель вечного двигателя.*

В данном случае приложение имеет несогласованное определение, выраженное падежной формой: *изобретатель **вечного двигателя***, а к определяемому слову относится согласованное определение: ***известный** экспериментатор.*

Оба варианта указаны в правилах, поэтому дефисное написание возможно.

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что написание "экспериментатор — изобретатель вечного двигателя" тоже не будет ошибкой? Ведь есть правило, что "...если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить а именно (особенно если приложение стоит в конце предложения, имеет зависимые слова и внутри него уже есть знаки препинания). *В дальнем углу светилось желтое пятно – огонь в окне квартиры Серафимы, пристроенной к стене конюшни* (М. Горький)". "*К нам подошёл экспериментатор — изобретатель вечного двигателя* [К нам подошёл экспериментатор, а именно тот, который изобрёл вечный двигатель]".

Comment: Это сочетание может обособляться тире по общим правилам в конце и середине предложения.  К нам подошел известный экспериментатор – изобретатель вечного двигателя. Известный экспериментатор – изобретатель вечного двигателя – подошел к нам. И в переносном значении (одно тире в середине предложения):  Изобретатели вечного двигателя – известные экспериментаторы и ученые // собираются на ежегодную конференцию в одном из европейских городов.